# how to set application icon in titanium mobile application?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have developed universal application using Titanium platform.
But I am not able to set ipad application icon appicon-72.png.

Can you please advice me how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do it is to create an info.plist file in the root of your project. You need to add:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>appicon.png</string>
        <string>appicon@2x.png</string>
        <string>appicon-72.png</string>
    </array>
```

for info.plist Creation try [this](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Custom+Fonts)

The info.plist file will now be used during building for distribution to appstore and the different icons will be correctly used in the binary.